# Read registry value names with specific encoding

Tags: c#, utf-8, registry

I normally read the values from `Registry` like this.

```
RegistryKey fileKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
fileKey = fileKey.OpenSubKey(path);
if (fileKey != null)
    string[] names = fileKey.GetValueNames();
List<string> values = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; ++i)
{
   values.Add((string)fileKey.GetValue(names[i]));
}
```

Is there a way to get the value with a specific encoding? For example `UTF-8`.

Comment: is there any particular reason why?

Comment: I have to read a value from registry which stored a specific path in windows. Now this path contains chinese character. I want to be able to read them.

Comment: What is being returned?

Comment: @Saruman return from `GetValueNames()` ? It returns `System.String`. Check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: which Represents text as a sequence of UTF-16 code units. there isnt a way off putting anything else in as far i knew.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. There is no "encoding" for `string` types, and so no "encoding" for string type registry values. If you are retrieving `string` values, then they have no encoding. Lacking an encoding, it makes no sense to ask for a _specific_ encoding. (Of course, the CLR uses UTF16 as the encoding to store text internally, but this is an implementation detail; from the C# programmer's point of view, there is no encoding until you convert `string` to `byte[]` or similar)

Comment: Encoding only becomes relevant when strings need to become bytes, or are read from bytes. You are not dealing with bytes, unless you're reading a bytes value from the registry.